# How to modify Android Bluetooth Chat to connect with A2DP device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I'm trying to modify the Bluetooth Chat program to connect with a device over the A2DP profile.  My tablet is already paired and connected to the device but when I launch the program it says it cannot connect. This is the only code that I have altered:

```
public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;

    mAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
}
    private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.A2DP) {
                mBluetoothA2DP = (BluetoothA2dp) proxy;
            }
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.A2DP) {
                mBluetoothA2DP = null;
            }
        }

    };
```

This is in the BluetoothChatService.java file. Above this code I have defined private BluetoothA2dp mBluetoothA2DP;